# PHP (Slim) routers don't work in subdirectory after hosting in Digital Ocean (Using Apache and Ubuntu 16)

Tags: php, apache, slim, digital-ocean, filezilla

I have a few different projects and all of them are set in `/var/www/html` folder. Each one has its own folder.
That's what I wrote in my virtual host to activate all of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    .
    .    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

One of my projects has routes in it - it's written in PHP using Slim micro framework.

The project is in `var/www/html/school` folder.

This is my **enabled** `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

All of the routers are at `routers.php` that is required in `index.php`
and they don't work: could you help me?

That's the website: http://www.itayperry.com/school/login
The login page is the only one that works - I've tried adding the word '/school' to every router in my routers.php file but this does'nt work.

[image]

I know that if I change my DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/school` the project will work perfectly but then all other projects will stop working.

Comment: You need to share your code here. We can't help from a screenshot and filenames alone. Have you called `$app->run()`?

Comment: I'm almost certain that the problem arises because of the `.htaccess` file and when I change the DocumentRoot the project works - but here's my code: https://github.com/itayperry/School-Project I would love for your help :)